# Check if checkbutton is checked in php after DIV reloaded

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

How should I check in php if checkbox is checked after button was clicked?

I tried to do like this, but nothing happens. It returns the answer of my first condition. I tried to put "checked" property on one of checkboxes, but code still doesn't work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#refreshList').on('click', function() { 
            var url = 'admin/thisPage.php';  
            $('#div1-wrapper').load(url + ' #div1'); 
         }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="active_registration" id="active_registration" value="" > active registration
        <input type="checkbox" name="coming_events" id="coming_events" value="" /> Comming events
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id=refreshList>refresh</button>
    </div>  
    <div id="div1-wrapper">
        <div id="div1">
            <?php
                if ( !isset($_POST["active_registration"]) && !isset($_POST["coming_events"])) {
                    echo "false/false";
                }                           
                if ( isset($_POST["active_registration"]) && !isset($_POST["coming_events"])) {
                    echo "true/false";
                }                                           
                if ( !isset($_POST["active_registration"]) && isset($_POST["coming_events"])) {
                    echo "false/true";
                }                               
                if ( isset($_POST['active_registration']) && isset($_POST['coming_events'])) {
                    echo "true/true"
                }
             ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I mean, if checkbox is checked...

Comment: The "value" attributes must be populated, as this is what is returned when they are checked.

Comment: In Javascript, document.getElementById('active_registration').checked 
In jquery $('#active_registration').is(':checked') or $('input[name=active_registration]:checked')

Comment: I will need to fetch data from database inside if conditions, so it would be better to find out the way how to do it in php.